# How to install oracle db in absolutely silent mode on WINDOWS with ant?

Tags: java, oracle, ant

We can install the oracle in "silent" in such way(as says oracle doc):

```
setup.exe -silent -response file
```

I can run that from ANT task for example.

But there are some troubles with this:
1) ant does not wait end of installation(because oracle installation runs in parallel relatively to ant)
2) during the installation need to do some actions and in the end we have to press enter.

Could somebody give me a advice about that?
May be we can write some .bat and run installation there in some way and so on..
In other words I need to write ant task that run installation of oracle in silent mode, then task waits installation, only then are run next ant tasks. And all this has to be in absolutely silent mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution looks in this way:

```
setup.exe -silent  -noconfig -nowait -waitforcompletion -response file
```